# How to get predictions from multiple fitted models

Tags: r, dplyr, drc

I have a data frame with calibration curves for multiple samples (signal s as a function of concentration c):

```
cal <- data.frame(sample = c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 8), rep("C", 8)),
                  c_std = rep(c(0, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200), 3),
                  s_std = c(40341, 24196, 13403,  6956,  3000,  1507, 312, 12,
                            40261, 24250, 13537,  6977,  2940,  1465, 304, 12,
                            40075, 24469, 13696,  7060,  2972,  1487, 307, 12))
```

Additionally, I have a dataframe with observations made on the same samples:

```
obs <- data.frame(sample = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  s_sample = c(1364, 4726, 521))
```

First, I fit models for each calibration curve using drm from the library [drc](/questions/tagged/drc).

```
model <- function(df) drc::drm(c_std ~ s_std, fct = LL2.3(), data = df)

library(dplyr)

cal_models <- cal %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, model)) %>%
  unnest(sample) %>%
  distinct(sample, model)
```

From the obtained models I want to get predictions for the observations I made on my samples. This is where I'm stuck. My idea was to merge the two objects containing the models and the observations by the sample ID and then apply predict from the stats package in a similar way as I used to fit the models with map. I don't know how to do this, though. This is how I merge the data frames:

```
dat <- merge(cal_models, obs)
```

And this is my approach to get predictions from the models, just that I would like to do this in one step for all samples:

```
cal_A <- subset(cal, sample == "A")
model_A <- drc::drm(c_std ~ s_std, data = cal_A, fct = LL2.3()
predicted <- stats::predict(model_A, data.frame(obs$s_sample[1]))
predicted
```

Comment: Bit confused why you would not fit one model for all your data? This approach gives 8*3 data for 3*3 parameters i.e., 8/3 data points per parameter, while one model would give 24/3 data per parameter. For your approach, you need to add `pred = map2(model,obs, predict)` in mutate. You also need `obs` to have same column names as the model data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The reason why I need multiple models is that each calibration curve was measured for a specific sample and therefore should only be used with this sample.

Comment: That depends if it is repeated measurements not if it is different samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to make a list of models using your calibration data like this:

```
models <- by( cal , INDICES = cal$sample , FUN = model )
```

Then mapplying `predict` over your `obs` data as follows:

```
mapply( FUN = function(x, y) { predict(models[[x]], data.frame(y)) }, 
   x=obs$sample ,  
   y=obs$s_sample)

A.Prediction B.Prediction C.Prediction 
    45.09688     18.07154     79.75994
```

If instead you want to add this to the existing data frame:

```
cbind(obs, prediction=mapply( FUN = function(x, y) { predict(models[[x]], data.frame(y)) }, 
        x=obs$sample ,  
        y=obs$s_sample))

             sample s_sample prediction
A.Prediction      A     1364   45.09688
B.Prediction      B     4726   18.07154
C.Prediction      C      521   79.75994
```

Comment: Looks like a neat solution. However, I would need the result as a dataframe with sample IDs in one column and the predictions in a second column. Could you help me to achieve this?

Comment: You could use `cbind` to combine the existing `obs` frame to the result from `mapply`.  I have edited my answer to include this

Answer (score 1):

```r
cal <- data.frame(sample = c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 8), rep("C", 8)),
                  c_std = rep(c(0, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200), 3),
                  s_std = c(40341, 24196, 13403,  6956,  3000,  1507, 312, 12,
                            40261, 24250, 13537,  6977,  2940,  1465, 304, 12,
                            40075, 24469, 13696,  7060,  2972,  1487, 307, 12))
obs <- data.frame(sample = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  s_std = c(1364, 4726, 521))
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
setNames(predict(drc::drm(c_std ~ s_std, fct = drc::LL2.3(), data = cal), obs), obs$sample)
#>        A        B        C 
#> 44.78515 18.20520 79.81111
cal %>%
    group_by(sample) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
        model = map(data, ~drc::drm(c_std ~ s_std, fct = drc::LL2.3(), data = .x)),
        pred = map2(model, sample, ~predict(.x, filter(obs, sample == .y)))
    ) %>%
    unnest(pred)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   sample [3]
#>   sample data             model   pred
#>   <chr>  <list>           <list> <dbl>
#> 1 A      <tibble [8 x 2]> <drc>   45.1
#> 2 B      <tibble [8 x 2]> <drc>   18.1
#> 3 C      <tibble [8 x 2]> <drc>   79.8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not reproduce your solution. nest() and unnest() require the library tidyr. When I load this library I get the following error: Error in `mutate()`:
``! Problem while
  computing `pred =
  map2(model, sample,
  ~predict(.x,
  filter(obs, sample ==
  .y)))`.
i The error occurred in
  group 1: sample =
  "A".
Caused by error in `log()`:
! non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

Comment: @empetrum It works for my `reprex` code.

Comment: Works now. It did not work at first because you renamed obs$s_sample to obs$s_std.

Comment: @empetrum Yeah I had it fixed only in my global enviorment